# dailymotion playerwebview no video only sound when app merged to other application

Tags: java, android, dailymotion-api

I created a sample app for dailymotion videos and it is working fine, it is playing videos when I click on video list. When I merged that app to my other existing application, everything is working fine except now I can hear only sound in playerwebview for video being played. What happened do not know, pls guide.

Here is code for xml for playerview

```
  <com.dailymotion.android.player.sdk.PlayerWebView
        android:id="@+id/dm_player_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
         />
```

and this is to play video

```
public void playvid(String videoId) {

        if ((getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
            mVideoView.setIsWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        mVideoView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);

        Map<String, String> playerParams = new HashMap<>();
        mVideoView.load(videoId, playerParams);

        mVideoView.setEventListener(new PlayerWebView.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(String event, HashMap<String, String> map) {
                switch (event) {
                    case PlayerWebView.EVENT_FULLSCREEN_TOGGLE_REQUESTED:

                        onFullScreenToggleRequested();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Pls guide.

one more thing it shows ad properly before start of video and then only sound with sometimes white box in player area or black screen.

Answer (score 0):

android:hardwareAccelerated="true" was false and creating the issue.